# How can I express "to be supposed to"?

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for a way to express certain circumstances. In English I've seen "is supposed to" and "should".

- You are supposed to clean the house today.
- He was supposed to bring the camera.
- He should have brought the camera.
- Do not mention your own opinions on the issue, unless you are supposed to.
- It was supposed to rain today.
- It should have rained today.

Comment: I didn't include a translation of "Do not mention your ... " in my answer because I'm not sure what it means in English.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two good ways to express this sort of thing. One is with a verb ending in *-u* and the other is the word *devus*.

Note that PMEG points out that "devus" suggests that the obligation is real but the activity is not done.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/povi_devi_voli/us.html

With that in mind, I would use the present tense for your first example (or -u.)

- Vi devas ordigi la domon hodiaŭ.
- Vi ordigu la domon hodiaŭ.

Note, by the way, the both -u and -us are timeless so if it's necessary to say that it happened at a certain time, this would be done by adverbs or other words that provide context.

- Kial li ne havas fotilon? Li devus kunporti la fotilon!
- Oni diris ke devus pluvi hodiaŭ, sed ne pluvas.

Your final example can be read a few different ways:

- Mi atendis pluvon hodiaŭ.
- Estas domaĝe ke ne pluvis hodiaŭ.